Prevent WooCommerce Shipping Rate ID from Changing for Each Zone
My shipping rate IDs seem to be different for each zone. For example it will be free_shipping:32 in zone 1, free_shipping:46 in zone 2, etc. I don't believe this is normally how WooCommerce functions. Would anyone happen to know what might be causing this and how to solve it?
This seems to be affecting every shipping method, not just free shipping.
I'd like to remove table rates from the cart if free shipping is available. Is there a way to get around the unique shipping instance ID in this function?
if ( isset( $rates['free_shipping:7'] ) ) {
    foreach ( $rates as $key => $value ) {
        if ( false !== strpos( $key, "table_rate" ) ) {
            unset( $rates[$key] );
        }
    }
}     
return $rates;


That is completely normal in WooCommerce: each shipping zone that you set, has its own UNIQUE Shipping Instance ID, which is part of the shipping rate ID and so different from one Shipping Zone to another. Note that you can set for example a Free shipping in some shipping zones and not in some others, or you can set multiple Free shipping in one shipping zone (same thing for other shipping zones types). So you can't prevent WooCommerce Shipping Rate ID from Changing for Each Zone.

Thanks so much @LoicTheAztec I didn't realize that was normal for WooCommerce. I've added a function to the original question. Is there a way to target instances of free shipping across all shipping zones without having to reference each unique shipping instance ID?

I better understand now… See my answer code below.

You can't prevent WooCommerce Shipping Rate ID from Changing for Each Zone, as each shipping method that you set has a unique instance ID, which is part of the Shipping Rate ID.
But you can target a shipping method type, like for example Free Shipping as follows:
add_filter('woocommerce_package_rates', 'filter_wc_package_rates', 10, 2);
function filter_wc_package_rates($rates, $package) {
    $free_shipping_found = false; // Initializing

    // Loop through available shipping rates
    foreach ( $rates as $key => $rate ) {
        // Check for Free shipping methods
        if( 'free_shipping' === $rate->method_id ) {
            $free_shipping_found = true; // Free shipping found
            break; // Stop the loop
        }
    }

    // If there is an available free shipping method
    if( $free_shipping_found ) {
        // Loop through available shipping rates
        foreach ( $rates as $key => $rate ) {
            // Target shipping methods rate Ids containing 'table_rate' sub string
            if ( false !== strpos($key, 'table_rate') ) {
                unset($rates[$key]); // Remove shipping method 
            }
        }
    }
    return $rates;
}   

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). It should work.
Important: You will have to empty your cart to refresh shipping methods cache.
